# Angular 7 & Stripe error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Stripe'

Tags: typescript, angular-cli, stripe-payments, definitelytyped, angular-cli-v7

I've installed `@types/stripe-v3` and included Stripe's javascript file in a script tag in `index.html`. Supposedly the Angular compiler should include all files automagically from the @types node modules. Reading up on the internet and looking at `@types/stripe-v3/index.d.ts` there should be a var Stripe declared globally if the file is included by the compiler. From `index.d.ts`

```
declare var Stripe: stripe.StripeStatic;
```

In my service file I have the following code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BetalingService {
  stripe = Stripe(environment.stripeKey);

  constructor() { }

}
```

Resulting in the following error:

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Stripe'.
```

Comment: how about defining import statement for Stripe?

Comment: If you try an import statement like `import { Stripe } from 'stripe-v3';` you get the error 'stripe-v3 is not a module', because the index.d.ts file indeed does not declare a module, it is meant to declare this global var Stripe upon inclusion by the compiler

Comment: `yarn add @types/stripe-v3 --save`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The issue is resolved by including a reference to the `@types/stripe-v3` package in the `compilerOptions.types` array of your `tsconfig.app.json` file in the `src` directory of your Angular project.

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": [
      "stripe-v3"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

This solution was posted by [bjornharvold](https://github.com/bjornharvold) in [this thread](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/15303).

Comment: In my case I was using `@types/stripe-checkout`. I was having the same problem and adding `stripe-checkout` to the `types` array didn't work. Instead I added `@types/stripe-checkout` to the array which solved the problem. Hopefully this can help someone else.

Comment: npm install --save @types/stripe-v3 (thought I'd suggest the explicit for any newbies)

Comment: @jesper exactly what i was looking for. i was digging around for hours.

Comment: I have my `tsconfig.base.json` and `tsconfig.app.json` files setup as described here. That removed the red squigglies in the editor, but the actual typescript compilation still complains with the error message mentioned by OP. :(

Comment: Try to delete the types array as mentioned in the answer below

Answer (score 8):

Angular imports types based on values of `compilerOptions.types` and `compilerOptions.typeRoots` from the typescript configuration file.
[TS compilerOptions docs reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types)

By default Angular projects created using angular cli will have two typescript configuration files.

1. `tsconfig.json` in the root of the project
2. `tsconfig.app.json` in `/src` directory

If both `types` and `typeRoots` are undefined angular will import all the typings from `node_modules/@types/*`.

But if any one of them have any value, only the specified types or the types from the specified location will be imported. E.g: `types: ['stripe-v3'] or typeRoots: ['/someDir']`. 
So all other installed types in `node_modules/@types/*` will not be imported.

If an empty array is set, then no types will be imported automatically from `node_modules/@types`. `types: [] or typeRoots: []`.

By default `compilerOptions.types` in `tsconfig.app.json` will have an empty array as its value. This is the reason why angular does not get the installed typings from `node_modules/@types/*` automatically.

To fix this: `npm install @types/stripe-v3` the typings and in `tsconfig.app.json`

1. Either add `stripe-v3` to the `types`.

```
...
"compilerOptions": {
   ...
  "types": ['stripe-v3']
}
```

2. Or delete types from compilerOptions

If you add, you will have to add all future typings to this array.

Instead if you remove `types` from `compilerOptions` angular will import all future typings automatically.

Also make sure to check `types` and `typeRoots` in `tsconfig.js` also. 
`typeRoots` will have relative paths as array and the same logic applies here as well.